# HTML-formatted emailing in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

How can I send a formatted email in codeigniter? I have this code which is sending email fine, but it is not formatting it as it should. You can see the picture which displays email received:

[image: html in email]

```
function email_sender()
        {
            //      $this->load->helper('form');
            // $this->load->helper('url');
            $config = Array(
                    'protocol' => 'sendmail',
                    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                    'smtp_port' => '465',
                    'smtp_timeout' => '7',
                    'smtp_user' => '****@****.com',
                    'smtp_pass' => '*******',
                    'charset' =>'utf-8',
                    'newline' => "\r\n",
                    'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
                    'mailtype' => 'html',
                    'header' => 'MIME-Version: 1.0',
                    'header' => 'Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8'
                );//initializing mail headers and information
            if ($this->input->post('submit')==true) 
            {
            $data['name']=$this->input->post('contact-name');
            $data['email']=$this->input->post('contact-email');
            $data['phone']=$this->input->post('contact-tel');
            $data['country']=$this->input->post('contact-country');
            $data['message']=$this->input->post('exampleTextarea');
            }//input from form
            $html_formattedEmail = $this->load->view('includes/email_template', $data, TRUE);//variable that loads view and save it as string
            $this->load->library('email', $config);
            // $this->email-> set_newline("\r\n");
            $this->email->from('abc@abc.com');
            $this->email->to($data['email']);
            $this->email->subject('Contact form submitted');
            $this->email->message($html_formattedEmail);
    
            if($this->email->send()){
                $data['main_content'] = 'thankyou_page';
                 $data['meta_title'] = 'abc';
                    $data['meta_description'] = 'abc2';
                     $data['meta_author'] = 'abc3';
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    
            }
            else{
                show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you used PHPMailer in Codeigniter Bilal?

Comment: nope, not with codeigniter but i have used php mailer with custom php!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this line of code, which will set mail type to `HTML`:

```
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
// load email library
$this->load->library('email');
```

// prepare email

```
$this->email
    ->from('ex@example.com', 'Example Test.')
    ->to('toex@example.com')
    ->subject('Hello Sample Test.')
    ->message('Hello, We are <strong>Htl content</strong>')
    ->set_mailtype('html');

// send email
$this->email->send();
```

You can also use a view file

```
$this->email
    ->from('ex@example.com', 'Example Test.')
    ->to('toex@example.com')
    ->subject('Hello Sample Test.')
    ->message($this->load->view('email_template-name', $dynamic-data, true))
    ->set_mailtype('html');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$config = Array(
    'mailtype' => 'html'
);
```

Add this to your mail config and recheck.

Comment: i have already added it but some how its not working but its working fine now after adding set_mailtype("html")

Comment: Glad to hear that the problem is solved one way or the other. Happy Coding!! :)

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter 4.1.1

This should work, but is completely ignored:

```
$email_config = [
  'mailType' => 'html'
];
$email->initialize($config);
```

So after you've loaded the Altmessage in you can use this completely undocumented function:

```
$email->setMailType("html");
```

and then load your html version message in as you normally would - which I'd not have been able to guess without the other answers provided on this page.